# How to optimize this SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select from a list of tables(list1,list2,list3,...) based on the select result from one table(tableA). How can I reuse the select result from that one table(tableA)?

my solution is

```
select * from list1 where list1.id in(select id from tableA where ...)
select * from list2 where list2.id in(select id from tableA where ...)
select * from list3 where list3.id in(select id from tableA where ...)
...
```

In my solution, *select id from tableA where ...* is executed by 3 times, it may take a lot of time, not efficient.
In my imagination, *select id from tableA where ...* should only be executed once.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: how are you using data from list1/2/3?

Comment: @almasshaikh show them on the screen.

Comment: did get you? Where is it?

Comment: @almasshaikh I mean the selected result from list1/2/3, will be displayed on the screen, viewed by the user.

Comment: If your tables in your list have the same column layout, you can consider doing `UNION ALL` to aggregate everything into a single result set. That may simplify your application code.

Comment: @OllieJones In this case, *select id from tableA where ...* still Performs 3 times.

Answer (score 2):

Two things to note.  First, in some versions of MySQL, the `exists` version is more efficient:

```
select *
from list1
where exists (select 1 from tableA a where a.id = list1.id and (...))
. . .
```

Second, you want to have the right indexes on `tableA` to optimize the query.  Basically, the right index is a composite index where the first key is `id` and the columns in the `where` clause follow.

The best way to order the columns in the index depends on the `where` conditions.  If the conditions are all equality conditions connected by `and`, then the ordering doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a temporary table to store the results of the subquery in memory and replace your subquery with a simple `IN (select id from tmptable)`. I assume your original subquery is slightly more complicated and maybe contains complex `WHERE` conditions:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable 
AS SELECT id FROM tableA WHERE complex = condition AND more = conditions;

SELECT * FROM list1 l WHERE l.id IN (SELECT id FROM tmptable)
SELECT * FROM list2 l WHERE l.id IN (SELECT id FROM tmptable)
...
```

As a result, the complex query is only executed once, the result is stored in-memory and is being re-used by the following queries.

Comment: Subqueries aren't eligible for query caching according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-operation.html

Comment: @OllieJones You're right, this is still not implemented in MySQL 5.6. I edited my answer accordingly. But MariaDB does. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/subquery-cache/

Comment: Yup, the MariaDB / MySQL difference caught me out too. I wish they'd get the common-table-expression stuff implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If all 3 SELECTs return compatible results you might try combining them using UNION ALL:

```
select *
FROM
 (
   select * from list1
   UNION ALL
   select * from list2
   UNION ALL
   select * from list3
 ) as dt
 where id in (select id from tableA where ...)
```

But I doubt that MySQL's optimizer can handle this well...

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a more efficient way to do this. There's no getting around the fundamental fact that you have to compare two lists with each other n times, where n is the number of list tables you have.

This is sort of like comtemplating the following set of additions:

```
a + 5 = ?
b + 5 = ?
c + 5 = ?
d + 5 = ?
```

Hey isn't there some way to optimise this? After all I'm just adding 5 every time!

No, not really. In this example you could write a function that added 5 to something and that would reduce the amount of code and be better from a DRY perspective. But that wouldn't "optimise" it in terms of reducing execution time.

Comment: sorry, i didn't make my intention clear. *select id from TableA* should be *select id from TableA where ...*, it may take a lot of time to execute this statement.

Comment: Oh. Well in that case NoDisplayName's answer was right. Perform the select once and cache it in a temporary table, then perform subsequent comparisons against that.